# Existence of Unitary Operator which Extends any inner product preserving operator in a Hilbert Space

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional Hilbert Space with a subspace $W$ Suppose $T:W\to V$ be a linear operator which preserves inner product i.e $\forall w_1,w_2\in W$ we have $\langle T(w_1),T(w_2)\rangle=\langle w_1,w_2\rangle$
I need to show the existence of a linear map $U:V\to V$ which is unitary and extends $T$.

suppose $\dim V=n,\dim W=k$

I chose a basis for $W$ say $\{w_1,\dots,w_k\}$ by extension theorem we can extend this basis to a basis of $V$ say $\{w_1,\dots,w_k,v_1,\dots,v_{n-k}\}$

Then I can define $U(w_i)=T(w_i)\forall i=1,\dots,k,U(v_i)=0\forall i=1,\dots,n-k$.

Is my extension correct?will be glad to have a hints or solution.

Comment: Try to work with orthonormal basis and orthogonal complements.

Comment: That definition will not give $\left\langle U({{z}_{1}}),U({{z}_{2}}) \right\rangle =\left\langle {{z}_{1}},{{z}_{2}} \right\rangle $ for $z_1$ and $z_2$ in V e.g take $z_1=z_2=v_1$. you need a slight change for the definition outside W.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I figured I'd post my answer for future people like me. I initially thought to tensor spaces together, but we want to add the dimensions of spaces, not multiply them.

As T preserves inner products, it must be unitary, so its eigenvectors $\{|i⟩\}$ span W. The key is to look at at the operator as the sum of its tensored eigenvectors, $$T=\sum_{i=1}^{k}|i⟩⟨i|$$ If we want our extended operator U to behave equivalently on space W, then its subset of eigenvectors spanning W must be the eigenvectors of T. Therefore, $$U=\sum_{j=1}^{n}|j⟩⟨j|\ where |j⟩ = |i⟩ for\ j=i=1..k$$
The question remains what acceptable values are for eigenvectors $k+1$ through $n$. Any choice that keeps $\{|j⟩\}$ an orthonormal set is fine, such as unit vectors along dimensions $k+1,...,n$. This will result in U acting as identity everywhere on V except subspace W.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Posting answers to old (unanswered) questions is just fine. I think your answer is essentially right. It's phrased in the language physicists use for operators (bra and ket notation) so may seem strange to most visitors here, who are more likely to be mathematics students.